Relacion de base de datos
Estoy en primer año de informática y me dieron cómo trabajo realizar un proyecto con java, elegi hacer una agenda pero estoy teniendo problemas en la relacion de la base de datos
CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
    id SERIAL primary key ,
    Nombre varchar(100) not null,
    Pass varchar(100) not null
)
CREATE table Contactos (
id serial primary key,
Nombre varchar(100) not null,
Apellido varchar(100) not null,
Numero int  not null,
Empresa varchar(100) not null
)

CREATE table Recordatorio (
    id serial primary key not null,
    Asunto varchar(100) not null,
    FechaInt date not null,
    FechaFin date not null,

)

CREATE table Notas (
    id serial primary key,
    Titulo varchar(100) not null,
    Descripcion varchar(100) not null

)

CREATE table Proyectos (
    id serial primary key not null,
    Nombre varchar(100) not null,
    descripcion varchar(100) not null,
    FechaInt date not null,
    FechaFin date not null
)

ALTER TABLE Contactos
ADD COLUMN usuario_id INTEGER;

ALTER TABLE Contactos
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_contacto_usuario
FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id)
REFERENCES Usuarios(id);


ALTER TABLE Recordatorio
ADD COLUMN usuario_id INTEGER;

ALTER TABLE Recordatorio
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_recordatorio_usuario
FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id)
REFERENCES Usuarios(id);

ALTER TABLE Notas
ADD COLUMN usuario_id INTEGER;

ALTER TABLE Notas
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_nota_usuario
FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id)
REFERENCES Usuarios(id);


ALTER TABLE Proyectos
ADD COLUMN usuario_id INTEGER;

ALTER TABLE Proyectos
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_proyecto_usuario
FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id)
REFERENCES Usuarios(id);


aun no tengo mucho conocimiento en sql y no se si esta bien relacionada

hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow. Revisa porfa como hacer una pregunta para que la comunidad te pueda ayudar ya que hacen falta algunos detalles importantes como por ejemplo que error es el que estas teniedno, cual es tu diagrama de base de datos que esperas obtener con ese codigo (un dibujo, un pseudo codigo ...)... https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Bienvenido a SO. Te invito a hacer el [tour]: Decir "tengo problemas" no es la mejor descripción de lo que te está ocurriendo. Si hay un mensaje de error, dejalo como parte del mensaje (texto, no imagenes). Si hay un comportamiento incorrecto o inesperado, cuál es ese comportamiento y cual es el esperado. Encontrarás más información en [ask].

Tu diseño de tablas se ve bien. Un usuario puede tener contactos, recordatorios, notas y proyectos, y por esto tienes las tablas con la usuario_id y los foreign keys. Los nombres de las tablas y de las columnas son muy buenos también. (Cosas serían más complicado si querías tener notas o recordatorios que pueden ser relatados a un proyecto opcionalmente por ejemplo.)

Claro, siempre hay cosas que pudieras mejorar. Una cosa es: ¿que es único en una tabla? ¿Quieres permitir dos notas con el mismo título? ¿Proyectos con el mismo nombre? ¿Proyectos con la misma descripción? Puedes crear indexes únicos para estas columnas o combinaciones de columnas. Además puedes añadir una fecha en la tabla nota para hacer posible ordenar las notas. Y añadir un estatus en la tabla proyectos. Etc.

Bueno antes que nada recuerda que aquí en StackOverflow la comunidad te exige generar el titulo con una pregunta. y en el post mencionar el error puntual de lo que te pasa, sea por una imagen o por código.
Revise el script y tienes un par de errores, lo corri en MySql y lo corregí.

Recuerda ponerle los punto y comas ";" ya que muchas veces los compiladores no toman las instrucciones sin ellos.
No es necesario crear llaves foráneas adicionales para cada tabla creando ALTER TABLES si desde la misma creación de tabla se pueden diseñar.
Como apenas esta aprendiendo recomiendo usar INT AUTO_INCREMENT en las llaves primarias, ya despues aprendera los UUID o  temas de Llaves Compuestas (Dos o mas llaves primarias).

Prueba el codigo como lo deje y pues funcionaria, tambien es bueno practicar temas de tablas muchos a muchos:
CREATE table Contactos (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Nombre varchar(100) not null,
    Apellido varchar(100) not null,
    Numero int not null,
    Empresa varchar(100) not null
);

CREATE table Recordatorio (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Asunto varchar(100) not null,
    FechaInt date not null,
    FechaFin date not null
);

CREATE table Notas (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Titulo varchar(100) not null,
    Descripcion varchar(100) not null
);

CREATE table Proyectos (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Nombre varchar(100) not null,
    descripcion varchar(100) not null,
    FechaInt date not null,
    FechaFin date not null
);

CREATE TABLE Usuarios (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT primary key ,
    Nombre varchar(100) not null,
    Pass varchar(100) not null,

    Contacto_id int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserContacts FOREIGN KEY (Contacto_id) REFERENCES Contactos(id),
    Recordatorio_id int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserRecordatory FOREIGN KEY (Recordatorio_id) REFERENCES Recordatorio(id),
    Notas_id int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserNotes FOREIGN KEY (Notas_id) REFERENCES Notas(id),
    Proyectos_id int,
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserProjects FOREIGN KEY (Proyectos_id) REFERENCES Proyectos(id)
);


Quisiera darte mi punto de vista sobre varias cosas que mencionas: - Imagenes solo para problemas netamente visuales. Todo lo demás, en texto, jamás imagenes. - No todos los lenguajes son compilados y no todos usan punto y coma. SQL no es compilado y hay dialectos dónde no se requiere ;. - Muchas personas prefieren crear las llaves foráneas después de crear todas las tablas. Es una cuestión de preferencia, yo podría decir: no hay necesidad de meter llaves foráneas en las sentencias de creación de tabla, si puedes usar alter table para crearlas después, y sería igual de incorrecto decirlo.

No siempre se debe usar auto incrementales. Si vas a recomendar su uso, sugiero que agregues tus argumentos de por qué debiera usarse siempre o alguna recomendación de cuando si y cuando no usarlos.  Ocurre lo mismo con UUID's y otras yerbas que no necesariamente tienes que aprender, ni antes ni después.  - Una llave compuesta no son dos o más llaves primarias, ¿o sí?

Al final, dices varias cosas como introducción de la respuesta, pero al final no explicas ni donde están los problemas del AP, ni cómo tu código los resuelve.

ste men... pero si tampoco dice cual es el problema que tiene, lo unico que hice fue refactorizar tu propio codigo que a ciegas dice que no le funciona pero no dice que puntualmente...

Entiendo, es uno de los problemas de responder preguntas mal planteadas. En la mayoría de los casos, es mejor dejar comentarios, y cuando se aclara, aventurarse a escribir una respuesta. Como sea, si refactorizaste el código, supongo que viste errores puntuales o cosas que, en tu experiencia , provocarían los supuestos problemas que dice tener el AP, ¿no?.  A lo que voy es que, darle este código, sin explicaciones, solo motiva a copiar y pegar, y el AP va a tener una estructura que va a seguir sin entender, solo para tener más problemas más adelante.  Resultado final, sigue sin aprender.

Tienes las relaciones al revés.
